# Coproduct and extension in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory

Can we consider the Coproduct of two objects in an abelian category as an extension of them the same as in the category of modules

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure. If $A,B$ are objects of an abelian category (actually linear category suffices), then $0 \to A \to A \oplus B \to B \to 0$ is exact.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. I would be grateful if could give me any reference for this.

Comment: Any book on abelian categories?